# Regex for no space or digit in the beginning

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that doesn't allow digits or spaces in the beginning. I've tried doing something like this:

```
^[\S][\D][\w+_.-]+@{1}[\w_.-]+\.{1}[a-zA-z]*$
```

However, when I use `4test@example.com` it says it's an email, but when I use `4test@example.com` it says it's not an email. In both cases, I'd like for it to say it's not an email. There shouldn't be a space or digit, how can I combine these two: `[\S][\D]` so that it works correctly?

Comment: Hint: Use a negated character class `^[^\d\s][\w_.-]+` ...

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your pattter `\S` will match any non whitespace char and it will also match a digit.

As mentioned in the comment, you can exclude matching the digit using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). If If you repeat the character class after that 1+ times the part before the @ should contain at least 2 characters.

If the minumum should be 1 char, you could use a `*` instead of a `+`.

Note that you don't need `{1}` and that `[a-zA-z]` can [match more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) than `[a-zA-Z]`

If you repeat the character class `[a-zA-Z]*` at the end 0+ times using `*` the match could possibly also match a dot only.

You could update the pattern to:

```
^[^\d\s][\w_.-]*@[\w_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qz7B3h/1)

---

If using `\S` is too broad, another option could be using a negative lookahead asserting not a digit followed by repeating the character class 1+ times:

```
^(?!\d)[\w_.-]+@[\w_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KqyYSC/1)